# Track the email for the multiple recipients

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am working on the application where I need to track the email for each recipients.
I tried this with pixel tracking method but this method is not accurate for the multiple recipient. I can not identify who had open the mail.

Is there any why so I can set different body for all recipient(to, cc and bcc) in the mail?
Thanks.

Comment: If you're sending e-mails in bulk, obviously every recipient will get the same message body, and also the same pixel with the same id. Only solution I see is sending individual e-mails, each one with its own tracking id.

Comment: @ChrisBE, Thanks for the reply.
I can not send individual e-mails for the cc and bcc recipients.

Comment: Then I'm afraid there's no way you can track individual events with the pixel method; they're all going to point to the same id...